# Reading Airflow rest API passed conf in script

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Hello I am trying to use the experimental Airflow rest API. Below is my Dag definition:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator,PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

seven_days_ago = datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(7),
                                  datetime.min.time())

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': seven_days_ago,
    'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('python_test', default_args=default_args)
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='testairflow',
    bash_command='python ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/dags/python_test.py',
    dag=dag)
```

and below is my script which simply reads the passed parameters and prints it.

```
import argparse


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Argument... ')
    parser.add_argument('--env', metavar='path', required=True, default='dev', help='Execution Environment')
    parser.add_argument('--config_path', required=True, help='Custom config s3 path..')
    parser.add_argument('--data_lake_bucket', required=False, default="s3://dl_bucket")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print("--------------------------------------")

    print(args.env)
    print(args.config_path)
    print(args.data_lake_bucket)


    print("--------------------------------------")
```

And below is my curl command to trigger it.

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/python_test/dag_runs \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"conf":"{\"--env\":\"dev\", \"--config_path\":\"this_is_conf\"}"}'
```

I am trying to figure out how to read the passed parameters with -d in the python script or any other job? Current I see the job is getting triggered but doesn't read the parameters.

Comment: What is the name of the file with  the DAG definition?

Comment: Dag file name os `python_release.py`

Comment: Why do you run `dags/python_test` in your curl command then?

Comment: My bad, as per official document the pattern is `dags/{dag_id}` my dag id was python_release in the post but its actually python_test. I changed it.

Comment: I am actually trying that out right now, yet to find any success though.

Comment: The experimental API is deprecated. Why would you spend time and effort on a deprecated feature?

Comment: Unfortunately we are still stuck with 1.10 version of Airflow, it is scheduled to be upgraded later this year but till that time I still have to use experimental API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimental API has been deprecated in Airflow 2 and will be removed in Airflow 3. I heartily recommend switching to Airflow 2 and switching to a fully-fledged REST API which has been implemented as part of the Airflow 2 effort and provides quite comprehensive, well structured, documented REST API with all the bells and whistles you can imagine. It's build with OpenAPI specification, it has Swagger UI, authentication support, we even have generated Python client to use the API: https://github.com/apache/airflow-client-python.

Also it is "Stable" and follows Airflow 2 SemVer versioning, so as long as you use Airflow 2, you have backwards-compatibility guarantees.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html

Airflow 1.10 (if you are still using it) has reached end-of-life on June 17 and it will not receive any more fixes (even critical fixes). In fact there have already been security fixes in Airflow 2 that has not been (and will not be) back-ported to 1.10, so it's highest time to upgrade.

You can also watch Airflow Summit's discussion panel about why you SHOULD upgrade https://airflowsummit.org/sessions/2021/panel-airflow-security/